# Implementing mediator design pattern for an observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, observablecollection

I have an application in which I'd like to implement the [Mediator Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator) in my MVVM application.

The issue is that it works for properties but it didn't for collections. I explain I have this class :

```
Public Class Eleve

    Private _Nom As String
    Private _Prenom As String
    Private _Age As Integer

    Public Property Nom As String
        Get
            Return _Nom
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Nom = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Prenom As String
        Get
            Return _Prenom
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Prenom = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Age As Integer
        Get
            Return _Age
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Age = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

In the first viewmodel I have this collection :

```
 Public Property LstEtudiants As ObservableCollection(Of Eleve)
            Get
                Return _LstEtudiants
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Eleve))
                _LstEtudiants = value
                RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs("LstEtudiants"))
                RaiseEvent UpdateGrids(value)
            End Set
        End Property
```

the Event `UpdateGrids` is handled in the mediator class :

```
Public Class Form1ViewModel


#Region "Classes collègues"
    Public objInfoViewModel As InfoViewModel
    Public objResultViewModel As ResultViewModel
#End Region

#Region "Constructor"
    Public Sub New()
        objInfoViewModel = New InfoViewModel
        objResultViewModel = New ResultViewModel
        AddHandler objInfoViewModel.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
        AddHandler objInfoViewModel.UpdateGrids, AddressOf OnUpdateGrids

    End Sub
#End Region


#Region "Methods"

        Private Sub OnChangingStatut(ByVal intAge As Integer)
            If (objResultViewModel IsNot Nothing) Then
                If (intAge > 0 AndAlso intAge < 10) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Enfant"
                If (intAge >= 10 AndAlso intAge < 30) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Adolescent"
                If (intAge >= 30 AndAlso intAge < 50) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Homme"
                If (intAge >= 50) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Vieux"
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub OnUpdateGrids(ByVal lstEleve As ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of Eleve))
            If (objResultViewModel IsNot Nothing) Then
                objResultViewModel.LstEnfant = New ObservableCollection(Of Eleve)(lstEleve.ToList.Where(Function(x) x.Age > 0 And x.Age < 10))
                objResultViewModel.LstAdolescent = New ObservableCollection(Of Eleve)(lstEleve.ToList.Where(Function(x) x.Age >= 10 And x.Age < 30))
                objResultViewModel.LstHomme = New ObservableCollection(Of Eleve)(lstEleve.ToList.Where(Function(x) x.Age >= 30 And x.Age < 50))
                objResultViewModel.LstVieux = New ObservableCollection(Of Eleve)(lstEleve.ToList.Where(Function(x) x.Age > 51))
            End If
        End Sub
    #End Region



    End Class
```

The problem is the event of the modification of the grid ( `UpdateGrids` ) is not raised or handled. So :

1. What is the error I commited?
2. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "With Events" in front of your _LstEtudiants declaration.  Then handle the collection changed event.  The *setter* of a **list** is usually not a place you care about in a MVVM application.  Typically the manipulation of items within the list is what you are going for.  Handling the collection changed event is where you would do that.